# How to stitch several PDF pages into one big canvas-like PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, pdflatex

I have a 32-page PDF of my family tree. Instead of having the family tree all on one really big PDF page (which is what I want), it is formatted so a group of 8 individual US letter-sized pages are supposed to be stitched across the width; 4 rows of this completes the tree. The margins of each page are all 22px.

If you visualize it in table form (where the numbers represent PDF page numbers):

[image: table]

I've tried to whip up some Python code to do this, but haven't gotten very far. How can I stitch the PDF so it can be one big page instead of smaller individual pages?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Here's the code I wrote. Sorry for not originally posting it.

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

STITCHWIDTH = 8;
currentpage = 1;

output = PdfFileWriter()
input1 = PdfFileReader(file("familytree.pdf", "rb"))

for(i=0; i<=4; i++)
    output.addPage(input1.getPage(currentpage))
    currentpage++;
    #do something to add other pages to width

print "finished with stitching"

outputStream = file("familytree-stitched.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Comment: PDF -> image (i.e. SVG) -> PDF would be an avenue I would research.

Comment: Hmm... good idea. I think I'll use Illustrator to try that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative to Ben Jackson's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577090/how-to-stitch-several-pdf-pages-into-one-big-canvas-like-pdf#6577225) of first converting to PostScript, and doing an "N-up" transform on the PostScript files, there's also a script called [pdfjam](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam), that can operate directly on PDF files.

Example:

```
pdfjam --nup 8x4 --landscape --outfile output.pdf input.pdf
```

The script is a wrapper for the pdfpages LaTeX package, recommended in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577090/how-to-stitch-several-pdf-pages-into-one-big-canvas-like-pdf#29377172).

Answer (score 2):

Use `pdf2ps` (part of Ghostscript) to convert the PDF to PostScript.  This is usually a lossless transformation.  Then use the techniques of http://www.tailrecursive.org/postscript/nup.html or any other "N-up" PostScript preamble to reorganize your pages.

The sample link combines a perl script to modify the PostScript to insert some snippets, but you can find more sophisticated examples which override `showpage` so that you can just insert your preamble with the redefined `showpage` at the start of your document.

Comment: If one does not want to edit the PostScript files directly, there's also a utility called `psnup` for creating "N-up" PostScript files. It is part of the PSUtils collection: http://www.tardis.ed.ac.uk/~ajcd/psutils/

Comment: @Ben Jackson: No, `pdf2ps` usually isn't lossless! (Old versions of Ghostscript convert PDF to PostScript Level 1. You'll loose the exact color information, you'll loose transparencies, you'll loose the original fonts in most cases, and some more...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a LaTeX installation around, I would recommend to use

1. the `pdfpages` package,
2. a little 10-line LaTeX script/document,
3. and the `pdflatex` command.

### The LaTeX script

Save the following LaTeX script as `8x4-letter.tex`. Adapt the `/path/to/input.pdf` accordingly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
  \definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9} % background color for complete poster
  \pagecolor{mygray}                  % line must *precede* \usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}          % comment out for testing
\usepackage[paperwidth=4896ppt, paperheight=3168]{geometry}
                                      % dimensions of 8 letter widths, 4 heights

\pagestyle{plain}                     % do not use page numbering
\begin{document}                      % orig. slide sizes are 612x792 pts (Letter)
  \includepdf[nup=8x4,                % 8x4 grid was asked for
              delta=0 0,              % horiz.+vert. distance between slides
              scale=0.999,            % scale down for additional margins
              pages={1-32},           % input document has 32 pages
              noautoscale=false,      % set to true if you have larger pages
              frame=false]            % set to true if you want frames
              {/path/to/input.pdf}    % filename+path cannot have spaces!
\end{document}
```

### The `pdflatex` command

Now run

```
pdflatex 8x4-letter.tex
```

This should produce a PDF file, `8x4-letter.pdf`.

If you want frames around each page, use `frame=true`. To add additional spacing between pages, use `delta=10 10` or `delta=17 11` or whatever suits you. You may want to change the value for `scale=...` too.